# How to set window specific browserAction button title

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setTitle it should be possible to set window-specific browserAction title using something like

```
browser.browserAction.setTitle({ title: 'foo', windowId: 3});
```

however I'm getting

```
 Error: Type error for parameter details (Unexpected property "windowId") for browserAction.setTitle.
```

Does this mean that this is simply not supported in firefox yet? I cannot find anything about this on the documentation page above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only supported from Firefox 62: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419893. The browser compat info noting this has been updated (https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/2586), but not yet deployed to MDN. That will probably happen today though.